# Backup standby database using LVM snapshot

Tags: postgresql, backup, snapshot

Objective:  Backup standby database (synchronous streaming replication) using LVM snapshot.

When running pg_start_backup:

```
postgres=# SELECT pg_start_backup('label');
ERROR:  recovery is in progress
HINT:  WAL control functions cannot be executed during recovery.
```

Is it possible to copy `backup_label` and `tablespace_map` from the primary database's cluster directory into the standby database's cluster directory in order to perform the LVN snapshot backup of the standby cluster directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BACKUP STEPS**

On Primary Database

1. Make sure primary db has  `archive_mode = on` in `base/postgresql.conf`
2. `select pg_start_backup(‘backup_label’);`

On Standby Database

3. backup the database using:
   `rsync –avr /var/lib/pgsql95/* /tmp/pgsql95/`
4. Transfer files generate by `pg_start_backup()`:
   `rsync -avr postgres@xxxxx:/var/lib/pgsql95/base/tablespace_map /tmp/pgsql95/base`

   `rsync -avr postgres@xxxxx:/var/lib/pgsql95/base/backup_label /tmp/pgsql95/base`

On Primary Database

6. `select pg_stop_backup();`
7. Transfer archive WAL files

   `rsync –avr /var/lib/pgsql95/archivedir/* \ 
   postgres@xxxxx:/tmp/pgsql95/archivedir`

**RECOVERY STEPS**

8. Edit `recovery.conf` in database cluster which is to be restored

`recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'`

`restore_command = 'cp -f /tmp/archivedir/%f %p </dev/null'`

9. Edit `postgresql.conf`
10. `pg_ctl –D /tmp/pgsql95/base start`

Comment: I might be missing something, but where is the LVM snapshot in this list of steps?  Also, in step 9, what has to be changed?

Comment: Yes it is missing.  I just tested the "theory", as the snapshots are taken by a different team.  

Replace the backing up of the database cluster and the archive WAL files (which in the above example use rsync) with the actual LVM snapshot commands.  I will ask the infrastructure team to provide the commands and post the update.

Comment: Changes in `postgresql.conf` are not necessary and depend on whether the database environment has any changes to it.  In my demo I had to change the database cluster base directory (from /var/lib/pgsql95 to /tmp/pgsql95) as I restore the database in a different directory; and the port (from 5432 to 5433).

Answer (score 3):

To do that on the standby server you need to configure it like a master server to enable the cascading replication[1].

> To enable it, you need to change the follow parameters:
>
> - `wal_level` to `archive` or `hot_standby`
> - If plan to use streamming replication:
>
>   - `max_wal_senders` to `2`
> - If you plan to use `wal` archiving:
>
>   - `archive_mode` to `on`
>   - `archive_command` to some place
>
> **Then restart your standby database.**
>
> When you configure that, you can run the `pg_start_backup` function without a problem.

To do what you need (backup with LVM) you must:

> **PLEASE test this steps on a test machine** to *avoid any issues* on your production database server.

1. run `pg_start_backup`:

   ```
   psql -U postgres -c "SELECT pg_start_backup('my lvm backup');"
   ```
2. make the lvm snapshot[2] (and export it to a file[3]), eg:

   ```
   ## Repeat that action for each tablespace
   ## TODO: Review max grow size for your snapshot
   lvcreate --size 10G --snapshot --name pgdata_backup_snapshot /path/to/pgdata/dir
   ## export the LVM to a image (with the `dd` command): 
   ### TODO: Replace the `vg_name` by correct one
   dd if=/dev/vg_name/pgdata_backup_snapshot of=/path/to/pgdata_backup.dd
   ## now remove the snapshot
   lvremove /dev/vg_name/pgdata_backup_snapshot
   ```
3. run `pg_stop_backup` function:

   ```
   psql -U postgres -c "SELECT pg_stop_backup();"
   ```

Hope it helps.

References:

1. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html#CASCADING-REPLICATION
2. http://www.tecmint.com/take-snapshot-of-logical-volume-and-restore-in-lvm/
3. https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_lvm_snapshots_p2
4. http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html

Answer (score 1):

I decided to "roll my own", eventually I spent quite much more work on it than expected, so I decided to publish my script:

https://gitlab.com/tobixen/pglvmbackup

One of the biggest complications for me was that the backup should be taken from the slave server, then it's required to do the pg_start_backup in a  "non-exclusive backup mode", which again means we cannot simply run a simple "pg_start_backup()" using pgsql ... we need to hold that session until the backup is done, which adds a bit of complexity when sticking to bash.  I ended up using the bash concept "coproc" for this purpose.

I see the other suggested solutions here is to run "pg_start_backup()" on the master server rather than slave server, I'm not 100% confident that this will have the intended effect.

Usage of pg_start_backup and pg_stop_backup may arguably be moot when doing an lvm snapshot, but I'd like to be on the safe side.